# Scrollable JPanel based on it's paintComponent

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane, paintcomponent

I am using `java-2d` to visualize my application. I've created the panel with extending of `JPanel` to draw a simple rectangle. I've named this `MyPanel`.

So, the width and height of panel dynamically changed by rectangle definition. I use `JScrollPane` to add scroll ability to my panel like below:

```
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(panel);
scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
```

I use below code to add my panel to window:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setSize(400, 300);
frame.setResizable(false);

MyPanel panel = new MyPanel();

JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(panel);
scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

frame.add(scrollPane);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Now, in `paintComponents` of MyPanel, I want to paint the rectangle with the width and height that are more than container (frame) width and height. But the scroll is not working.

What is wrong? 
Could any one help me?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scroll pane uses the components preferred size to determine how big it should be and provides scrolling when the components size is larger then size of the scroll pane...

Try overriding the `getPreferredSize` method of the custom component and return the size you want

If the size of `MyPanel` changes over the runtime of your program, use a reference to a `Dimension` (returned by getPreferredSize) and call `revalidate` when you change it

Comment: Thank you :) I should use this dimension in `paintComponent` to draw rectangle, Right ?!

Comment: Yes, in your paintComponent, you should be using getWidth and getHeight, remember, preferredSize is a hint, but JScrollPane will generally honour it...

Comment: I can't understand "preferredSize is a hint", could you explain more ?

Comment: A layout manager may use a combination of getPreferred/Minimum/MaximumSize to make determinations about how a component is sized, this is how layout managers work, but they are able to ignore these values and make there own decisions, so, in your code, you shouldn't always rely on what you want or think the size of the component  should be, but sometimes, that's the point. As a general rule of thumb. I rely on the actual size of the component, but there are those times when I can't as what I'm painting must be a particular size, such as is your case ;)